# Spring security: hasAnyAuthorizy wildcard

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Currently, we have this king of `@PreAuthorize` expressions:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SCOPE_all.adm', 'SCOPE_qdcac.edi', 'SCOPE_qdcac.pet', 'SCOPE_qdcac.con')")
```

Is there any way to tell something like `SCOPE_qdcac.*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PreAuthorize` accepts a SpEL expression so you could write your own expression

Something like

```java
@Component
class ScopeSpel {
  public boolean hasScope(Authentication authentication) {
      // do your check(s) here
  }
}
```

and use it like `@PreAuthorize("@scopeSpel.hasScope(authentication)")`